# Checking if a String array contains a specific string

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a string array(`String []words`) which gets populated during runtime and contains almost 400k members. I tried to check if the array contains a specific string :

```
boolean check=Arrays.asList(words).contains ("code");
```

I know the `"code"` is already within the array, but i never get the check true as if the checking process isn't even taking place. I also tried with Hash sets but with no success. Can anyone tell where the problem is???

Comment: Is "code" by itself as one of the elements, or is it _part_ of one of the elements? `List#contains(someString)` will check if `someString` _equals_ any of the _elements_ in the List, not if it's contained by any of them.

Comment: Your approach [would work, if the array actually contains "code"](https://ideone.com/VrWgCd). Are you certain it contains that, and not, say `"code\0"` i.e. with non-printing characters?

Comment: Post your [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. So create an array with 2 or 3 entries. Then invoke your above statement. Get that working first to prove to yourself that the method works. If it doesn't work then you have a simple program to post in the forum and we can help. Once you have proven to yourself that the above method works then you know that: 1) your Array doesn't contain the data you think it does or 2) the data is not in the format you think it is. We can't help you because we don't have access to your data.

Comment: I am totally sure that the array contains "code" , but the check always fails. I can get the members with words[i.e. 500] method.

Comment: @DeepeshPaul Try trimming the members of the `String[] words` first and then give it a shot.

Comment: `I am totally sure that the array contains "code" ` - prove it by using my suggestion with a couple of hard coded entries. Once that works then create a loop that loops from 0 to 40k and adds the string representation of your index to the array. This way you can check if the problem is the size of the array. Again if this works, it gets back to your data.

Comment: For the record: you should either enhance your question regarding [mcve], or well, consider accepting an answer at some point. I am pretty sure that you were told all the things that matter here in the end ...

Answer (score 1):

For the given problem, the answer isn't really clear, as the question is a bit unclear. Most likely, your 400K elements don't contain "code" (for example you forgot to trim input, and there are spaces/newlines around).

But beyond that, a distinct *non-answer* here: when you have 400K elements to search in, then your idea of doing `Arrays.asList(words).contains ("code");` is simply a bad idea.

Walking through 400K elements in order to figure if one entry matches a search word is terrible inefficient. You see, if you want to look up only one word, then why storing all the data in memory? So you probably intend to search for *different* words over time. And each time, you want to iterate 400K elements to figure if a word is present?

Instead: you should invest into a more appropriate data structure. That could be a (Hash)Set, or a (Hash)Map, or even beyond that (like a full text search enabled service, using Solr, ElasticSearch, ...)

Seriously: repeatedly iterating 400K elements on a *mobile* device is *not* something that your users will appreciate. Not at all.

Comment: I tried using Hash sets by adding all array members in a Hash set and using its contains() method, still with no success. I should mention that calling words[714] gives the clear output of "code" but checking is failing . i am really puzzled where i am wrong.

Comment: Then do as Andy suggested: compare words[714] and "code" character by character: print them one by one, and maybe put around each char, like `print("<" + singleChar +">");` And note: of course, set.contains() and list.contains() give the same result for the same input data. It is just about the **cost** of getting that result!

Comment: I tried words[714].length () which gives output 4 , where is the place of any additional character?

Comment: As the others keep telling you: either the array contains invalid values, or the search string. It could be as strange as "c0de" using a 0 (zero), not an o (oooh). Try it yourself: `Arrays.asList("code").contains("code")` will return true. So when your array doesnt contain, then it doesn't contain the search string.

Answer (score -2):

**Try below code. I hope it will help you.**

boolean check=Arrays.asList(words.matches("(.*)code(.*)"));

Comment: Your () brackets are in the wrong place. Your regex is wrong, the whole idea is terrible.

Comment: I"m no regex expert but I believe that will match on words that contain the string, not  on just the exact word. In any case using a regex is extra overhead and is not necessary if the data in the array is as the user expects. If it is not in the format they expect then they have a problem somewhere else when they load the data into the array. So the better solution is to fix the data problem, not devise a workaround to the data problem.

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know if it works. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @DeepeshPaul As said: it won't compile as it is written right now. Then, when you fixed the syntax, it will slow down your program. And then, most likely, it won't change anything about the result.

Comment: It works on string values as  I tried it will return  true in check varieble

Comment: (1-)  `It works on string values as I tried` - Did you try: `System.out.println( Arrays.asList( "scoded".matches("(.)code(.)") ) );`? It will also return true.